# Oracle SQL, Recursion, Spreadsheet calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, spreadsheet, calculated-columns

I want to transfer a calculation from an Excel spreadsheet to an Oracle SQL Query.

There are three predefined columns `ID`, `IncommingDate` and `ProcessingTime`.

Now I want to calculate two additional columns namely `Processing Start` and `Processing End`.

The result should look as follows:

[image: Result Excel]

With the Formulas:

[image: Formula 1]
[image: Formula 2]

One can see that the `ProcessingStart` of one entry should be the maximum of its `IncommingDate` and the `ProcessingEnd` of the previous entry.

How can I achieve this using SQL?

I have prepared an example query here:

```
WITH example AS
    (
        SELECT
            1                                                       AS id,
            to_date ('01.01.2018 00:00:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') AS IncommingDate,
            60                                                      AS "Processing Time [sec.]"
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            2,
            to_date ('01.01.2018 00:05:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mi:ss'),
            60
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            3,
            to_date ('01.01.2018 00:05:30','dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mi:ss'),
            60
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            4,
            to_date ('01.01.2018 00:10:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mi:ss'),
            60
        FROM
            dual
    )


SELECT
    *
FROM
    example
```

Does anybody of you knows a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use recursive subquery factoring:

```
with rcte (id, IncommingDate, ProcessingTime, ProcessingStart, ProcessingEnd) as (
  select id,
    IncommingDate,
    ProcessingTime,
    IncommingDate,
    IncommingDate + (ProcessingTime/86400)
  from example
  where id = 1
  union all
  select e.id,
    e.IncommingDate,
    e.ProcessingTime,
    greatest(e.IncommingDate, r.ProcessingEnd),
    greatest(e.IncommingDate, r.ProcessingEnd) + (e.ProcessingTime/86400)
  from rcte r
  -- assumes IDs are the ordering criteris and are contiguous
  join example e on e.id = r.id + 1
)
select * from rcte;

        ID INCOMMINGDATE       PROCESSINGTIME PROCESSINGSTART     PROCESSINGEND      
---------- ------------------- -------------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 2018-01-01 00:00:00             60 2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 00:01:00
         2 2018-01-01 00:05:00             60 2018-01-01 00:05:00 2018-01-01 00:06:00
         3 2018-01-01 00:05:30             60 2018-01-01 00:06:00 2018-01-01 00:07:00
         4 2018-01-01 00:10:00             60 2018-01-01 00:10:00 2018-01-01 00:11:00
```

The anchor member is ID 1, and can do a simple calculation for that first step to get the start/end times.

The recursive member then find the next original row and uses `greatest()` to decide whether to do its calculations based on it's incoming time or the previous end time.

This is assuming that the ordering is based on the IDs, and that they are contiguous. If that isn't how you are actually ordering then it's only a bit more complicated.

Comment: Dear Alex, thank you very much for your answer. Even if I don't understand this statement it works totally fine.